# Throwing exception due to CCBlock?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I'm using some code from RAYWENDERLICH, which is a great site, but thats not the point. The code that I got off the site that is given me a hard time is this (Im adding a monster/ghost that is supposed to move on the screen):

```
- (void) addMonster {

CCSprite * monster = [CCSprite spriteWithImageNamed:@"Ghost.png"];

// Determine where to spawn the monster along the Y axis
CGSize viewSize = [CCDirector sharedDirector].viewSize;
int minY = monster.contentSize.height / 2;
int maxY = viewSize.height - monster.contentSize.height/2;
int rangeY = maxY - minY;
int actualY = (arc4random() % rangeY) + minY;

// Create the monster slightly off-screen along the right edge,
// and along a random position along the Y axis as calculated above
monster.position = ccp(viewSize.width + monster.contentSize.width/2, actualY);
[self addChild:monster z: -4];

// Determine speed of the monster
int minDuration = 2.0;
int maxDuration = 4.0;
int rangeDuration = maxDuration - minDuration;
int actualDuration = (arc4random() % rangeDuration) + minDuration;

// Create the actions
CCActionMoveTo * actionMove = [CCActionMoveTo actionWithDuration:actualDuration
                                                        position:ccp(-monster.contentSize.width/2, actualY)];
CCActionCallBlock * actionMoveDone = [CCActionCallBlock actionWithBlock:^(CCNode *node) {
    [node removeFromParentAndCleanup:YES];
}];
[monster runAction:[CCActionSequence actions:actionMove, actionMoveDone, nil]];

}
```

The above code is added above the init method, while this is added inside the init method:

```
//How often a new ghost gets produced
      [self schedule:@selector(gameLogic:) interval:1.0];
```

And after the init method I have the call back method as follows:

```
//The call back function
-(void)gameLogic:(CCTime)dt {
[self addMonster];
}
```

However, I'm getting an exception thrown at me a couple of seconds into running the app leading to a termination. The message in the Debugger reads as follows:

```
-[__NSGlobalBlock__ removeFromParentAndCleanup:]: unrecognized         selector sent to instance 0x10ef5ee20
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSGlobalBlock__ removeFromParentAndCleanup:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10ef5ee20'
```

So as far as my understanding goes there is something wrong with the block method, but I can't seam to figure out exactly what.

Got any clues to how I might fix this and/or what's wrong with the code and why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not certain what 'node' refers to in your `addMonster` method, but if you want to vanish monster after its move, you probably meant :

```
[monster removeFromParentAndCleanup:YES]; // monster, not node
```